# Jest unit test nextjs _app component

Tags: unit-testing, next.js, jestjs

I have a nextjs _app component that I would like to add some unit tests.

```
import { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

import * as gtag from 'lib/gtag';

const App: FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps, router }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
      gtag.pageview(url);
    };
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default App;
```

This is an extension of the question posted here. (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13717)

has anyone experienced this before?